# How do I get a variable from my login controller to be available to all views in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am new to coding and I'm building my first real application which uses the EVE Online ESI API.  I have a login controller set up that redirects the user to ESI to login and handles the callback.  So far I can successfully connect and retrieve data like the username, token, etc into a variable in my login controller and I can pass that variable immediately to a view.  My problem is figuring out how to make that variable available to all views.

I have tried using View::share('user',$user);  in the login controller but it's not working.

In my web.php I have these routes:

```
Route::get('login/eveonline', 'EVELoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('login/eveonline/callback', 'EVELoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

I have this in my EVELoginController.php file:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Socialite;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\User;
use View;

class EVELoginController extends Controller {

    /*
    | Redirect the user to the EVE online authentication page.
    |
    | @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */

    public function redirectToProvider() {

        return Socialite::driver('eveonline')->redirect();

    }

    /*
    | Obtain the user information from EVEOnline.
    |
    | @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    |
    */

    public function handleProviderCallback() {

        $user = Socialite::driver('eveonline')->stateless()->user();

        return View::make('successful-eve-login',$user);        

    }

}
```

With this code the view gets the variable and I can use it in the HTML of the view.  But the variable doesn't get stored anywhere so that it can be retrieved by other views later.  What is the best way to go about getting the data into other views? Forgive me for being very much a noob but I'm trying.

Comment: You can access logged in user information globally using `auth()->user()`. It'll give you logged in user model out of the box.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I need.  Say I want to get the my user's character name from the Eve Online API which I can do using the login controller I set up.  I can store that character name in a variable and then pass the variable to a view so that the character name is available to be used in the view.  But how do I take that variable with the character's name in it and make it available to any view I call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to share user variables with multiple views by creating a session. Like login session or normal session.

you can look at these official docs.
[Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session)

[Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication)

Comment: I think this looks promising.  So the idea is to save the data to the session and then the views can retrieve the data from the session?  I'll try implementing this and let you know how I'm doing later today... have to get some sleep for now.

Comment: Ok i didn't get back to sleep, I instead researched Laravel Session and was able to get the variable saved to the session with: Session::put('character', $user['CharacterName']);   and then I was able to retrieve it from another view with: $character = session('character', 'default').   Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Just make sure. Do not store **sensitive info** in session